# How to find listview in 'fragment'

Tags: android, fragment

I am having a fragment that send request to server and download json , then parse it into a listview , somehow i can't reach the view properly.below is some part of my apps , this is my first touch on listview with fragment , ***for some reason i only allow to use Fragment so i choose '`setAdapter`' instead of '`setListAdapter`' to be my adapter***

myfragment.java

```
 public class gallery extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag2_layout,
                    container, false);
            return myFragmentView;
        }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .........
    .........
    .........
    setAdapter(colorAdapter);

    }
```

layout.tab_frag2_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#ffffff">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding"
    android:tag="listf" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My expectation is using

`MyListView = (ListView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.list);`

to get my view , but it doesn't work that way...
Now I just want to get my listview and apply

`MyListView.setAdapter(colorAdapter)` to it

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Do you use a ListFragment?

Comment: Just like in Activities where you have a ListActivities in fragments you have a ListFragment.

Comment: Do you mean the only way is to exends ListFragment to get this work?

Comment: That is the general way, I'm not sure you can do it other way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option1: Since your fragment layout consists of just a simple ListView.
Consider using

> public class gallery extends ListFragment

Then you can use this code to get your listview.

> myFragmentView.getListView()

Option2: As Nickolaus mentioned, you need a custom id if you want to use findViewById.

> android:id="@+id/listview1"

Comment: Thanks for sharing me new stuff on android , it works =)
Took the second option

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a ListFragment, you need to add a custom id (android:id="@+id/custom_id") then you can use findViewById to find the ListView

Comment: android:id="+@id/my_custom_id" am i doing it wrong ? eclipse gave me a string type error

Comment: android:id="@+id/custom_id"